# Can we validate in Service of Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

```
static constraints = {}
```

In documentation they said that it work in Domains . Can we apply constraints in services if we create variables in it ?

Comment: By default, access to service methods is not synchronised, so nothing prevents concurrent execution of those methods. In fact, because the service is a singleton and may be used concurrently, you should be very careful about storing state in a service. Or take the easy (and better) road and never store state in a service.

Comment: @Abdullah if the question was something like "Tell me a good technique or best practice when using services" your comment would be a good response. It has next to nothing to do with the actual question that was asked however. It's not about state - it's about _mutable_ state, and more specifically _mutating_ mutable state. Nothing changes the `constraints` block at runtime, so it would not be a thread safety concern.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith- I will keep this in mind in future, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we apply constraints in services if we create variables in it ?

Yes.  A long time ago we introduced the `@Validateable` annotation which allows you to make just about any class which is written in Groovy, including Service classes, validateable.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/validateableservice which includes the following:

grails-app/services/demo/PeculiarService.groovy

```
package demo

@grails.validation.Validateable
class PeculiarService {

    String someString

    static constraints = {
        someString matches: /[A-Z].*/
    }
}
```

test/unit/demo/PeculiarServiceSpec.groovy

```
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(PeculiarService)
class PeculiarServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test validation"() {
        when: 'someString begins with a lower case letter'
        service.someString = 'invalid'

        then: 'validation fails'
        !service.validate()

        when: 'someString begins with an upper case letter'
        service.someString = 'Valid'

        then: 'validation passes'
        service.validate()
    }
}
```

Note that if your service has state like this you almost certainly don't want the service to be a singleton, which is the default scope.  Also, there is almost certainly no good reason to ever make a service validateable but the answer to the question as asked is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're asking, i.e. drop a `constraints` block into a service and expect it to be recognized and used. For one, which domain class(es) would that block pertain to? A service isn't tied in any way to an individual domain class, so it would be more involved than just creating a block.

You can externalize validation however. Grails uses Spring MVC under the hood, and the validation support from that. It's not obvious that this is happening, but if you look at all of the beans in the `ApplicationContext` you'll see that each domain class has an associated validator bean that implements Spring's `Validator` interface, and it uses the rules defined in `constraints` blocks to do validation. You can do something similar by implementing that interface and doing whatever checks you like. It would be tricky to parse a constraints block because it has a custom DSL, so you'd need to see how Grails parses it and do the same thing.

I wrote about this [in my book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do) if you want to see more details. I would copy/paste that here - I'm not trying to generate sales - but it's somewhat far fetched and you're really better off using the standard approach. I only figured out how to do what I described for fun and thought it'd be interesting to add to the book to illustrate one of the many ways Grails uses Spring.

Comment: Yes I know that but our problem is that , we are using Neo4j Database using Spring Data Neo4j , But we are not using Grails plugin for Neo4j . SO if we create our Domain in Domain package then Grails create problem , So we decided to create our Domain in any other package , that's why I am asking this question
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the grails docs (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#validation):

> Most commonly they are applied to domain classes, however URL Mappings and Command Objects also support constraints.

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't validate service. Better look at command objects or [@Validatable](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#validationNonDomainAndCommandObjectClasses) annotation.